# Conditionally return Model Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm very new to Laravel,

I was wondering how can we apply some condition on Model.

Suppose there's a field `is_public` if this field is `false`
so then only admins can see this data..

I dont wanna do this on controller with where clauses, as in future I might use the Model in many places, also relations..

Comment: If my answer was helpful, consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Laravel Global Query Scope` is what you looking for.

> Global scopes allow you to add constraints to all queries for a given model. Laravel's own soft delete functionality utilizes global scopes to only retrieve "non-deleted" models from the database. Writing your own global scopes can provide a convenient, easy way to make sure every query for a given model receives certain constraints.

Basically, it can apply any clause globally.

What we can do is, define a `GLobal Query Scope` on our `Model`,
so every time our Model is called, we can check if the user is not a Admin or someone who doesn't have permission to view private data then extend our query with a where clause like `where('is_public', true)`.

here's an example

`App\Models\YourModel`

```php
   namespace App\Models;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder; // Dont forget to include

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('visible', function (Builder $builder) {
            if (!optional(auth()->user())->can('The Permission Name')) {
                $builder->where('is_public', true);
            }
        });
    }
```

There's many more things you can do with Query Scopes, like suppose you dont want this global scope to be used somewhere you can do:

```
YourModel::withoutGlobalScope('visible')->get();
```

Learn more about `Query Scopes`
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 3):

I think a good solution would be policies: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies

> Policies are classes that organize authorization logic around a
> particular model or resource. For example, if your application is a
> blog, you may have a App\Models\Post model and a corresponding
> App\Policies\PostPolicy to authorize user actions such as creating or
> updating posts.

You could create a policy for your model like so:

```
php artisan make:policy YourModelPolicy --model=YourModel
```

Then maybe something like this for the view method:

```
public function view(User $user, YourModel $model)
{
    if ($user->isAdmin()) return true;

    if ($model->is_public) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You _could_ using [accessor and mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) but I wouldn't recommand has it will probably be more difficult to maintain and could lead to unexpected results. I think the proposition made by Feel The Noise is a better alternative. Policies are made for this purpose. At the end the difference is that you would use `$user->can('view', $model)` or `@can('view', $model)`

Comment: There's also an option of using Laravel Global Scope, In there we can check if the `auth()->user()->isAdmin()` is true then return the query as it is, and if false extend the the query with a where clause like `$query->where('is_public', true)`. I would write a complete answer soon, currently commenting from my mobile. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes